# A benefit of implicit casting (to boolean) in Groovy

Tags: groovy, casting, implicit-typing

I'm coming to Groovy from statically typed languages. And I don't understand what is the benefit of having an implicit conversion to bool? I see this feature quite controversial than useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a convenience. It is easier and shorter to write conditions like `someMap` than `someMap!=null && !someMap.isEmpty()`. Yes, there are libraries that can do both of those checks for you in a single call, but then you get `MyAwesomeLibrary.makeThisTestForMe(someMap)`.

With Groovy it's just less code.

Also, you can customize the behavior by overriding the `asBoolean` method to whatever you like/need for whatever reason.